# Sign out user via REST HTTP API

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I can sign in users to Firebase using this [HTTP API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential):

How do I sign out users, so that the Firebase `idToken` and `refreshToken` can no longer be used?

Also, how long is the `refreshToken` valid for?

If my user does not use my app for weeks, can I still use the `refreshToken` or will I need to get a fresh Google Sign In `idToken` and exchange it for a Firebase (`idToken`, `refreshToken`) pair via the `/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion` API?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a sign out endpoint. You could try doing a redirect to https://accounts.google.com/Logout but I suspect that is signing out from all Google services which might not be a great idea.

The whole point of Refresh Tokens is that they can be used to access resources whether or not the user is present and signed in, so your comment "How do I sign out users, so that the Firebase idToken and refreshToken can no longer be used" is an oxymoron.

A Refresh Token is theoretically valid until a user specifically revokes it, but your app should code for the possibility that Google has expired it.

Comment: So if a refresh token is compromised, my app cannot expire it to prevent further use? I would have to rely on users to expire their own tokens some how? As an example, I was expecting I could let the user "sign out" and have their id and refresh tokens no longer valid so if they are compromised after the sign out it is no issue.

Comment: @zino - 1) why or how do you think that a Refresh Token can be comprimised? Your webserver (site, etc.) receives the Refresh Token as part of OAuth and not the client. 2) Each OAuth provider provides a logout endpoint, which you could lookup manually and then provide as a bonus feature on your website. However, this would log a user out all sites and not just yours.

Comment: The code is running on an React Native iOS app. It seems a bit strange how you can sign users in, but you cannot then sign them out (invalidating the idToken and refreshToken for future calls).

Comment: the refresh token is the property of the user who granted access. That user can revoke the token. If you really want your app to invalidate a RT, you can request approx 30 new RTs which will cause the oldest to be expired. As John says, the RT should be stored securely on a server, not distributed to an insecure client.

Comment: There is no server apart from the Firestore REST API. All code is on the client: The user signs in with Google, which results in an `idToken`. I pass that `idToken` to Firebase Auth at `/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion`, and the response is an (`idToken`, `refreshToken`) pair. I use this `idToken` in the `Authorization : Bearer $idToken` header for all Firestore REST API requests *from the client*. The Firestore DB is designed to be used directly from the client - how would it be possible to prevent having an refresh/id token on the client in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The client cannot directly revoke the ID token via the REST API, but both the Firebase Auth client SDKs (ex: [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signOut())) and the [Auth Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) do support it. So if your client platform isn't supported, but you are able to create a small server implementation (maybe through Firebase/Cloud Functions), you can create an HTTP endpoint that triggers ID token revocation.